# Java - Scriptlet to class conversion

Tags: java, performance, jsp

I'm trying to take any jsp scriptlets in my project and convert them to model classes. Because we all know scriptlets in our jsp are evil. Except this one snippet of code is really giving me problems when I try to separate it out into a class. It's a fairly simple bit of code that loops through child nodes. Here is my jsp which works just fine:

```
<%
  NodeIterator ni = currentNode.getNodes(); 

  while (ni.hasNext()) {
  Node nii = ni.nextNode();
  String printNodeTitle = nii.getProperty("fileReference").getString();
  %>
  <img src="<%= printNodeTitle %>" />
  <%
}
%>
```

Here is the code in my model class:

```
public class fileReference(){

    Node currentNode = (Node) context.getAttribute("currentNode");
    NodeIterator ni = currentNode.getNodes();

    while (ni.hasNext()) {
        Node nii = nodeLoop.nextNode();
        String printNodeTitle = nii.getProperty("fileReference").getString();
    }

    public String getPrintNodeTitle() { return printNodeTitle; } 
}
```

The strange thing is I don't get an error I just simply get no output. Any ideas? Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Why you prefer to convert the scriptlet to model(class).  Its loss of effort and time. So, my suggestion is to use EL and JSTL for better security.

Comment: nodeLoop? where it is defined?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your variable ni should be iterable, so the while loop should look like this:

```
while (ni.hasNext()) {
```

I don't know where did you take the nodeLoop variable... probably it's just an empty list iterator?

Comment: thanks @igor. That was an oversight on my part. Even adding ni to be iterable I'm still getting nothing. Any other ideas? Thanks!

Comment: The same thing inside the loop: change
Node nii = nodeLoop.nextNode();
to 
Node nii = ni.nextNode();

Comment: Also, I can make some suggestions: if you can run your server in debug mode, just add a breakpoint inside this method and look at the variables.
If you can't do it, you can always add a System.out.println with some trace information. I like adding those after each line of code like this: System.out.println("step 1") to see if you get to this step (e.g. inside the loop)